# ALS Ice Bucket Challenge Videos

Tags: discussion

This is the archive for the ALS Ice Bucket Challenege Videos made by our members.

Answer (score 4):

- Lucas Kauffman: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-Ia1PtQzHg&list=UUdWj06mqb1pvz32EpaTvsJg&index=1

Answer (score 4):

- Rory McCune:
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8HciFu7W4KY&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4):

- Scott Pack: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5lcwGtg_N3A&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 4):

- Rory Alsop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv6UFEfGiXk

Comment: Kilt? Check. Alcohol? Check. Hello Kitty in the background? Check. I approve of this video.

Answer (score 4):

- Simon: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7NGdYFQEzs

Answer (score 4):

- AviD - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SqOut5nNGSM

Answer (score 3):

- TildalWave: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D9ZVd8JXU_w

Answer (score 3):

- Kisu and Adnan: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wac-rscByN0